# how to setup a mail server in windows xp pro?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, email

How should I setup a email server in windows xp pro ?

Comment: you shouldn't, you should use a server os to run a mail server

Comment: But I am developing a web application in my windows XP pro and I want to develop and  test email integration with the web app. How can i do it ? I am not employed in any company to use their mail server. I am just a student sitting in my home developing this small web app

Comment: Do you need to receive incoming mail or just send outgoing mail?

Comment: I need to receive and send mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Xmail](http://www.xmailserver.org/) in the past for development testing on an XP laptop (I generally agree with the comment above - if you're running a production MTA you probably don't want to use XP)

Answer (score 0):

I'll third the suggestion above of not using XP for a production mailserver, but for development and testing purposes [hmailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/) is a good, free option.